# PHP/HTML tables and buttons that link to different a page/website

Tags: php, html, button, hyperlink

I have a table on my website that displays data within it. There are 3 buttons next to the data, Update, Join and Delete.

The Update and Delete buttons are functioning correctly, but with the join button I have had no luck fixing. What I wan the join button to do is link to a website on click, for example, I want it to go to this page once the user clicks the join button: `http://localhost:3000/`.

I have been experimenting with the `a` tag instead of the `input` tag which I would prefer to use as I am using the `input` tag for the other buttons and have had no luck getting it to work. I'm a beginner with all this, help is much appreciated and thank you in advance!

My Code:

```
echo "<table>
   <tr>
   <th>Title</th>
   <th>Description</th>
   <th></th>
   <th>Update</th>
   <th>Join</th>
   <th>Delete</th>
   </tr>";
   while($record = mysql_fetch_array($myData)){
   echo "<form action=findGroup.php method=post>";
   echo "<tr>";
   echo "<td>" ."<input type=text name=name value='" . $record['form_name'] . "'/> </td>";
   echo "<td>" ."<input type=text name=description value='" . $record['form_description'] . "'/> </td>";
   echo "<td>" ."<input type=hidden name=hidden value='" . $record['form_id'] . "'/></td>";
   echo "<td>" ."<input type=submit name=update value='update" . "'/> </td>";
   echo "<td>" ."<a href='localhost:3000' />" .  " >Join</a></td>";
   echo "<td>" ."<input type=submit name=delete value='delete" . "'/> </td>";
   echo "</tr>";
   echo "</form>";
  }
  echo "</table>";
```

Comment: You forgot the scheme from the URL (`http://`) … and you have a random, junk `/>` after the href attribute too.

Comment: Oh you need help alright; did you know that `mysql_*` functions are deprecated (since PHP 5.5) and removed since PHP 7? Switch over to the more secure and friendly classes for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php). Rumor has it, everytime a `mysql_` function is called, a unicorn dies. Stop killing the unicorns.

Comment: "the join button I have had no luck fixing" — Questions should include *a clear problem statement*. Describe the expected and actual behaviour. You should also include a [mcve] (emphasis on minimal). If the problem is HTML not behaving the way you want: Show the HTML output of the PHP and not the PHP. (If it that the PHP doesn't generate the output you want, then show the desired and actual output).

Comment: @IsThisJavascript lmao, I will update the functions :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be single quote if you don't have to use dynamic variable, just echo the html directly like below.

A URL must start with protocol `http://` and  `/>` this refers to self closing of element since you require `<a>` tag you don't need to use self close.

```
echo "<td><a href='http://localhost:3000'>Join</a></td>";
```

> A URL has two main components:
>
> **Protocol identifier:** For the URL http://example.com, the protocol
>   identifier is **`http`**. 
>   **Resource name:** For the URL http://example.com, the
>   resource name is **`example.com`**.

Comment: Thank you very much! Problem fixed :)

Comment: Yep, there's a time limit to when I can accept the answer, waiting on that :D

Answer (score 1):

There is one bracket too much in that line (`>`). Also, you can omit some of the quotes in there:

```
echo "<td><a href='http://localhost:3000'>Join</a></td>";
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, the button still won't link to the web page, any idea on how to fix this? :)

Comment: Thanks, the problem is fixed now :)